# i have a problem with using relative clause " of which " in my sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

The sentence is as follows:

> A(name of a country) is determined to build a moderately prosperous community within 20 years, the key of which is to improve the livelihood standard of farmers who account for 70% of the total population.

The sentence is written by myself. When I was writing, I was wondering did I use "of which" grammatically correct here (it sounds natural to my ear though). I wanted using "of which" to refer to "build a moderately prosperous community". However, I wasn't 100% sure. Did I do that right? Or rather, there might be a better way to get my idea across to readers.

Comment: Please mind that the first letter of the first word needs to be capitalized. But I already helped you edit it, so this problem is solved now.

Comment: The usual idiom is "living standard", not "livelihood standard", but everyone would understand the way you have written it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the phrase

> the key of which is to improve the livelihood standard of farmers

formally refers to the noun "community", because, if we strip the sentence to its bare minimum, it would be

> France is determined to build a community, the key of which is to improve the standards.

You see? It's a bit awkward. "The key of community is to improve the standards". The reader will logically understand the meaning, which is:

> France is determined to build a community **with the key goal of** improving the standards.